# Is there a logit-normal equivalent of to sp.stats.norm.ppf in python? (or other languages...)

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

If I want to do something like the following:

# using normal inverse CDF
param_values2[:,0] = sp.stats.norm.ppf(param_values2[:,0],0,np.pi/2.)

To convert samples (param_values2) on the interval [0,1] to a uniform distribution, but I wanted to convert them to a logit-normal distribution, how would I go about doing this? I can't find anything useful out there on this so far... Wisdom/knowledge from others would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to **legit-normal distribution** ?

Comment: Sure. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution

Answer (score 0):

You might construct your own distribution following https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html. The more you define private functions, the better distribution would be. At minimum, you need _pdf() and _argcheck defined, everything else would be computed (slowly!) on the fly.

Basically, if you provide _pdf(), then parent pdf() call would jusr redirect to _pdf(). If you provide _cdf(), then cdf() will call _cdf().
But if no _ppf() implementation is provided, parent class will make it up for you from _pdf(), _cdf() and all other pieces you provided.

Sample code (lightly tested!) to get you started

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
from scipy.special import erf

SQRT2 = np.float64(1.4142135623730951)

def logit(x):
    return np.log(x/(1.0-x))

class logit_norm(rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self, x, μ, σ):
        if x == 0.0:
            return 0.0
        if x == 1.0:
            return 0.0
        return 1.0 / (σ * np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)) * np.exp(-0.5 * ((logit(x) - μ)/σ)**2)/x/(1.0-x)

    def _cdf(self, x, μ, σ):
        if x == 0.0:
            return 0.0
        if x == 1.0:
            return 1.0
        return 0.5*(1.0 + erf((logit(x)-μ)/SQRT2/σ))

    def _argcheck(self, μ, σ):
        s = σ > 0.0
        return s

np.random.seed(seed=111)

lgtn = logit_norm(name='logit_norm', a=0.0, b=1.0)
test = lgtn.rvs(μ=2.0,σ=1.0,loc=0.0,scale=1.0, size=100000)
```